# Як, де, в якій традиції виникло слово "вальтер-скоттівський"/"вальтерскоттівський"?

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви, запозичені-слова, неологізми

В літературознавсті на позначення історичного роману певного типу використовують термін "вальтер-скоттівський".

Ось, наприклад, у [статті Євгена Барана "Художня проза Ореста Левицького"](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Baran_Yevhen/Khudozhnia_proza_Oresta_Levytskoho.pdf):

> Від П. Куліша до О. Маковея письменники крок за кроком вдосконалювали традиційний вальтерскоттівський метод написання історичних романів, співвідносячи його із культурно-політичною національною специфікою.

Зрозуміло, що цей прикметник утворений від імені анґлійського письменника Вальтера Скотта. Тоді лоґічно припустити, що запозичений він з анґлійської мови.

Звичайні анґло-українські, російсько-українські, тлумачні словники результатів не дають.

Шукаю в Ґуґлі [walterscottish](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=XOJJW_aLF8itsAHGsIXABA&q=%22walterscottish%22&oq=%22walterscottish%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i19k1j0i13i30i19k1j0i8i13i30i19k1l6j0i8i13i10i30i19k1.833.3851.0.4228.2.2.0.0.0.0.187.187.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.185....0.yHFn9fkikBE), знаходить 38 результатів, що для анґломовного Ґуґлу десь так само як нуль, половина з тих посилань повторюється, ще половина - взагалі не викликає довіри.

Шукаю ["walter scottish"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22walter%20scottish%22&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpgs2Uwp7cAhVGkSwKHS-vA9EQBQgkKAA&biw=1366&bih=662), результатів вже більше, але більшість - це просто щось на кшталт "Walter, Scottish writer/novelist".

#### Отже, питання:

Чи можна дізнатися, де виник цей термін і як потрапив до українського літературознавства? Якщо можна, то як.

Чи, може, це українська вигадка, адже нам важливо наголосити на "вальтер-скоттівському" характері "Чорної ради" Куліша (бо цей роман для українців - певна віха)?

Comment: А чим не підходить очевидний варіант — номіналізація/субстантивація власного імʼя, яке супроводжується неблагозвучністю прямої номіналізації за одним лише прізвищем (*скоттівський* і особливо *scottish* versus *Scottish* = шотландський)?

Comment: @bytebuster це може бути відповіддю на питання "як", але не на питання "де, в якій традиції". Тобто, це питання передусім про походження, місце виникнення і шлях до української цього терміна, не знаю, чи "етимолоґія" - правильне визначення. Це можна зрозуміти, власне, з останніх кількох абзаців.

Comment: Щодо запозичення - маю великі сумніви. А жульвернівський треба шукати у французьких словниках? Пошук у Ґуґлі дає купу посилань на довідники з російської орфографії.

Comment: Пошук "жульвернівський" дав книжку "Україньска без помилок, де вказано що такі слова пишуться через дефіс: "жан-жаківський", "жуль-вернівський", "вальтер-скотівський" https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=fOwVCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT136&lpg=PT136&dq=%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=DBsE3J8zCR&sig=KUWaUbfkMkGbSqCx7q-F1JsjxgQ&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFopq7paPcAhWHh6YKHbDeBU8Q6AEIUjAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false

Comment: @Artemix наше літературознавство великою мірою ізольоване від загальносвітового процесу, мені цікаво, чи "вальтерскоттівський"/"вальтер-скоттівський" - частина тої ізоляції, чи ні. звідки воно прийшло, хто вигадав тощо.

Comment: @P.Vovk Re: *"де, в якій традиції"* — авжеж, в українській традиції. Інакше — оффтопік на цьому сайті.

Comment: @bytebuster ось є слово "кіхотичний", вигадали від Дон Кіхота робити прикметник не українці, ми просто запозичили це. Це таке саме питання, як етимолоґія. Слово в українській мові, а походження може бути в іншій (а може бути і в українській також, але поки це невідомо, то я питаю про шлях, який пройшло це слово у своєму становленні, включно зі шляхом з іншої мови, якщо такий був).

Answer (score 3):

Найдавніше використання слова, що мені вдалося знайти, - це у вересні 1838 у місячному періодичному шотландському виданні ["Tait's Edinburgh Magazine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tait%27s_Edinburgh_Magazine). Слово "**walter-scottish**" використовується в примітці до статті на її першій сторінці (*12 рядок примітки*). У [статті](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=KuARAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA559) автор критикує серію романів "Walladmor", які позиціонувалися як вільний переклад роману Вальтера Скотта "Waverly", що, звичайно, не сподобалось шотландцям.

Взагалі, відношення земляків Вальтера Скотта складно порівняти з чимось, бо він відродив національну та історичну пам'ять народу і відкрив її для світу. Це яскраво видно ще на початку статті, де автор згадує Вальтера Скотта як "Author of "Waverly" ('Author' з великої літери), що має на увазі, що кожен, хто читає статтю, знає автора цього роману.

Отже, відповідь на запитання: так, дізнатися щодо етимології цього слова можна шляхом дослідження джерел, зокрема періодичних видань. Слово "вальтер-скоттівський" безумовно не є вигадкою українських літературознавців, бо ймовірно використовувалось ще за життя письменника. А вальтер-скоттівським романтизмом називають період, у який письменники зверталися до історичного минулого, шукаючи у ньому відповіді на проблеми сучасності. До цього руху відноситься й роман П. Куліша "Чорна рада".